# unable to produce data to mqtt proxy from localhost to docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, proxy, mqtt, confluent-platform

i have build this docker composer file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-zookeeper:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-server:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    expose:
      - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://broker:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9093
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-schema-registry:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:9093'

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.2.0-5.4.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9093'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-${CONFLUENT}.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-enterprise-control-center:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
      - kafka-mqtt
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9093'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb-server:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-ksqldb-server:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9093"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-ksqldb-cli:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  rest-proxy:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-kafka-rest:${CONFLUENT_DOCKER_TAG}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9093'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'

  kafka-mqtt:
    container_name: kafka-mqtt
    hostname: kafka-mqtt
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-mqtt:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 1884:1884
    environment:
      KAFKA_MQTT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_MQTT_LISTENERS: 0.0.0.0:1884
      KAFKA_MQTT_TOPIC_REGEX_LIST: mqtt.temperature:.*temperature
      KAFKA_MQTT_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

everythings work fine but when i tried to publish some data from outside docker to the mqtt proxy nothing happen, im using mosquito pub :

```
mosquitto_pub -h 0.0.0.0 -p 1884 -t mqtt.temperature -q 2 -m "99999,2.10#"
```

i got this error : Error: Connection refused

i dont know whats the problem here??

ps: i can produce data from kafkacat directly to the topic but its not what i want...all i want is to get data from mqtt producer from my host into kafka mqtt proxy.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid remote address

Comment: even if i put localhost or my IP 192.168.2.10 , its the same ....
only if i put localhost:9092 in mosquito , i got connection lost error, and theres and exception in the broker log, its about the socket size or something like this ...

Comment: `localhost` would be the best starting point. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61420562/edit) the question to include the error messages so we can see what they are.

Comment: the same doesnt work.. thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

On the kafka-mqtt configuration "network_mode" can not be "host" (https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) and the KAFKA_MQTT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS must refer to the internal docker listener (in case INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093). Remove the "network_mode" and change the KAFKA_MQTT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS. Bellow follows the code that i'm using and that its working.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  kafka-mqtt:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-mqtt:latest
    ports:
      - "1884:1884"
    environment:
      KAFKA_MQTT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka1:19092"
      KAFKA_MQTT_TOPIC_REGEX_LIST: temperature:.*
      KAFKA_MQTT_LISTENERS: "0.0.0.0:1884"
```